# null reference exception in level manager script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm basically brand new to unity and C# and have been following along with tutorials online (N3K 2D Platformer, YouTube), I'm trying to create a basic UI to display score etc and I seem to have come across a null pointer exception which I can't seem to figure out as I have referenced the two objects that are causing this error, namely my scoreText object and my hitPointText object.

As I've said I did reference those very objects by dragging them from my hierarchy and into the fields I had created in my level manager script in the inspector and further to that I am simply following along with a tutorial and have done exactly as the video has instructed, but yet on the video it seems to work fine.

The offending lines of code are:

```
    scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    hitPointText.text = hitPoints.ToString();
```

This tutorial is now over 1 year old, is it possible that a unity update has changed that way things NEED to be referenced?

I'll post my level manager code below in the hopes that someone may be able to point out the error that I seem to be missing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static LevelManager Instance { set; get; }

    public Transform spawnPosition;
    public Transform playerTransform;
    private int hitPoints = 3;
    private int score = 0;

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text hitPointText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        hitPointText.text = hitPoints.ToString();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update ()
    {
        if(playerTransform.position.y < (-10))
        {
            playerTransform.position = spawnPosition.position;
            hitPoints--;

            if(hitPoints <= 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Your Dead!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Win()
    {
        Debug.Log("Victory");
    }
}
```

Snippets of screens below:

[Scene view of unity engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p2ke.png)

[Game view of unity engine, with game running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg7A0.png)

So here is a snippet of code from my player class which uses Instance on the LevelManager script in order that it can have access to the win() method as can be seen in the last case of the switch "WinPost", not sure if that is what you are referring to when your mentioning singleton, other than that never is the term singleton used in any of the scripts I have.

```
switch (hit.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "Coin":
                Destroy(hit.gameObject);
                break;
            case "JumpPad":
                verticalVelocity = jumpForce * 2;
                break;
            case "Teleporter_1":
                controller.enabled = false;
                transform.position = hit.transform.GetChild(0).position;
                controller.enabled = true;
                Debug.Log("This works!");
                break;
            case "Teleporter_2":
                controller.enabled = false;
                transform.position = hit.transform.GetChild(0).position;
                controller.enabled = true;
                Debug.Log("This works!");
                break;
            case "WinPost":
                LevelManager.Instance.Win();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: I'd guess you forgot to assign the variables of `scoreText` and/or `hitPointText` in the Unity Editor (when you look at the properties of the GameObject that was assigned this script)

Comment: Also, null *pointer* exception is from Java, what you are facing is a null *reference* exception,

Comment: yeh sorry im from a java background so a little Freudian slip there

Comment: Are you using the Singleton `Instance` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the components aren't initialized when you call `Awake`. `Awake` gets called as a constructor-kind-of method as soon as the object is created. When it is called, you can't be sure if the other components got initialized already.

I would suggest you copy the assignments you make in `Awake` into `Start` and come back to see if it works. Start gets called after the `GameObjects` have their components initialized.

```
private void Awake()
{
    Instance = this;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    hitPointText.text = hitPoints.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I see what you were getting at there with the possibility of the objects maybe being referenced before they've even been created but unfortunately, it still gives the null reference exception even after shifting the object reference call shifted into the Start(), and of course with the same 2 lines being the offending code.

Comment: Have you made sure that these Components are still assigned to the `LevelManager` when you run the game in the editor?

Comment: Yes, both of these objects are still assigned to the level manager script once the game is run, I've updated my original post to include some snippets of the scene view and the game view with the game running. As can be seen, both the score text and hit point text objects are still assigned to the level manager script.

Comment: It is interesting that it actually does what is intended as can be seen in the game view by the UI changing to reflect the score and hit points as per the level manager script.

Comment: You just wrote what I wanted to write...
Anyways: Have you tried debugging it by setting a breakpoint or by dumping out all the variables used in this scenario into the console? This may help more than the speculation I can do here. You may want to try that now and come back with the results.

Comment: I shall go and learn what that is, do it and report back, thanks for your help.

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard, maybe start here: https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/debugging-unity-games-visual-studio

Comment: So the debugging pretty much told me what i already knew which was that the two Text objects scoreText and hitPointText have null values, my problem is that i cant instantiate them with something like: new Text(); as it wont allow me to do this due to the Text objects access modifier, so im left wondering how i can instantiate a Text object if the access modifier wont allow me???

Comment: This sounds wierd. You show that it is working with your screenshots, but you get an Exception thrown anyway. They are both null, although they can't be. Have you tried to reload Unity or create a new scene where you try to recreate that scenario (not the whole game, just this)? Unity is wierd sometimes.

Comment: You can't instantiate Components with new, this is a restriction of the game engine. But I just read a comment on your original post, which I like to have answered aswell: Do you use the Singleton Instance anywhere?

Comment: So, I had to update my original post as it was too long for here, ill go and try to recreate this in a new scene.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for trying to help and all the great suggestions.

Ultimately I ended up breaking my game in the process of trying to recreate the same UI in a new blank scene, I did manage to recreate the same error before breaking my game which at the time then left me none the wiser. However due to the fact I broke my game I had to step back at least two tutorials and recreate the level manager object and the empty child spawnPosition object, (the level manager script was ok, it was just the level manager object and its child that I broke), anyway in having to recreate both of those objects again everything now seems to work as intended and so this leads me to the conclusion that the problem was not the code but the objects themselves???

Thanks again to everyone that tried to help, another day another learning experience.

D.